# EditText in listview, Getting forcefuly closed and got null pointerexception

Tags: android

I am doing very basic thing just write a code of list view with edittext and i used two row layout here. at the 1st time when my app will run on that time no edittext will be activated bt once i click on edittext it will activate and after making changes again it will deactivate. 
but problem is that when i set click listener on edittext its getting proper postion but when i try to do any modification with its data i got null pointer exception. `package

```
com.android.bank.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.bank.R;
import com.android.bank.model.AccountData;

public class AccountListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<AccountData> acountData = new ArrayList<AccountData>();
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_MORE_RECORD = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_MORE_RECORD + 1;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();
    private ViewHolder holder = null;
    public AccountListViewAdapter(Activity context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //  this.acountData = acountData;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return acountData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void addItem(final AccountData item) {
        acountData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_MORE_RECORD : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }
    public void addSeparatorItem(final AccountData item) {
        acountData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(acountData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
         TextView txtViewAccountHolder;
         TextView type;
         EditText ammountEdt;
         ImageView arrow;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bank_account_row, null);
                   holder.txtViewAccountHolder = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.actType_textView);
                    holder.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type_textView);
                    holder.ammountEdt = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ammount_edt);
                    holder.arrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_image);
                     break;
                 case TYPE_MORE_RECORD:
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bank_account_addmore, null);
                     holder.txtViewAccountHolder = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addMore_textView);
                     break;
             }
             convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
             holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
         }


        try {
            holder.txtViewAccountHolder.setText(acountData.get(position).getAccountHolder());
            holder.type.setText(acountData.get(position).getAccountType());
            holder.ammountEdt.setText(acountData.get(position).getAmmount());
            holder.ammountEdt.setId(position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.txtViewAccountHolder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(context, position+"pos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



        /*///we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
        holder.ammountEdt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    final int position = v.getId();
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                    Toast.makeText(context, Caption.getText().toString()+"pos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     ;
                }
            }
        });
*/



        if(holder.ammountEdt != null)
        {
        holder.ammountEdt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, holder.ammountEdt.getText().toString()+"pos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        }

        return convertView;
     }

 }
```

LogCat is given bellow:

```
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.bank.adapter.AccountListViewAdapter$2.onClick(AccountListViewAdapter.java:154)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-29 08:41:38.834: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the log or the line of code where the NPE occurs?

Comment: Either remove  if (convertView == null) condition or findViewById should be out of this condition.

Comment: check this "holder.ammountEdt.getText().toString()" i think this is null

Comment: Hi Zaz ... getting null pointer exception

Comment: I solved it.. i was doing a silly mistake, here i am using two different layout in my list view there were some id conflict problem. thanks for every one to support ...

Answer (score 0):

```
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Do this code in constructor
Then in your child returning function get reference if view is equal to null.

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, parent, false);
```

Do same in group also.